# Issues caching Python pip packages in Gitlab CI

Tags: python, caching, pip, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to create a Gitlab CI pipeline that will install python packages via pip, which I can then cache and use in later stages without the need to re install them each time.

I have followed the [CI docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html) on how to do this, but I'm facing issue. They say to create a virtual environment and install via pip there, however after creating and activating the venv the packages aren't installed in the venv. Instead they're installed in

> /builds//ca-cert-checker/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages

Also, in a separate stage when the cache has been downloaded the stage is looking for a dir that doesn't exist

> venv/bin/python

gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - setup
  - before_test


variables:
  PYTHON_IMG: "python:3.10"
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
    paths:
      - .cache/pip
      - venv/

python_install:
  image: $PYTHON_IMG
  stage: setup
  script:
    - python3 --version
    - pip install virtualenv
    - virtualenv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - pytest --version    #debug message
    - pip show pytest     #debug message

pytest_ver:
  stage: before_test
  image: $PYTHON_IMG
  script:
    - ls venv               #debug message
    - ls .cache/pip         #debug message
    - pytest --version      #debug message
```

In the pipeline this causes the setup stage to run and cache successfully

Successful cache creation:

> Creating cache default... .cache/pip: found 185 matching files and
> directories  venv/: found 3292 matching files and directories

Output from pip show pytest:

> Location: /builds//ca-cert-checker/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages

So pip isn't installing within venv, which I think is the issue.

---

When I run the before_test stage I get the following output:

```
// Ommited for brevity

Checking cache for default...
Downloading cache.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/<project-number>/default 
WARNING: venv/bin/python: chmod venv/bin/python: no such file or directory (suppressing repeats) 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:00
Using docker image sha256:33ceb4320f06dbd22ca43809042a31851df207827b4fc45cd6c9323013dff7c7 for python:3.10 with digest python@sha256:b58c3f2846e201f5fc6b654e43f131f5a8702f8d568130302d77fbdfd9230362 ...

$ ls venv
bin
lib
lib64
pyvenv.cfg
share

$ ls .cache/pip
http
selfcheck

$ pytest --version
/bin/bash: line 128: pytest: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any help / advice on how to get the pip dependencies to install in the venv and cache properly would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I see that your installation is done in different jobs (and even two different steps), but each job / step is a different thread / instance so the installation step does not retain anything for the next step.
You should do the installation in a `before_script`, `pip` will find the cache

```yaml
image: python:3.10

stages:
  - setup
  - before_test

variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
    paths:
      - .cache/pip
      - venv/

before_script:
    - python3 --version
    - pip install virtualenv
    - virtualenv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - pytest --version    #debug message
    - pip show pytest     #debug message

pytest_ver:
  stage: before_test
  script:
    - ls venv               #debug message
    - ls .cache/pip         #debug message
    - pytest --version      #debug message
```

Comment: But then won't I have to run this before script with each stage that I want to use a package in. For example, I want to run some tests with pytest in one stage and then run a .py file in another. 

Isn't the point of cache that I only have to install files in one stage and then they can be re used in later stages without needing to install them again as they're re used from the cache?

Comment: The [`before_script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#before_script) section will be executed before each job (unless it is overloaded).

The cache is not meant to contain programs (and probably can't), it is meant to contain dependencies and avoid having to download them again. The cache will contain all the package installation files (archives). This will be like doing an offline installation.

Comment: What is this caching exactly? If the pre-script runs before all jobs, won't all packages be downloaded for each job? If so, what is the point of caching?

Comment: This is explained in the [GitLab's doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/).
The cache is reused by the following jobs, we save the time of downloading packages because they are in the pip cache.
The pre-script is not really executed before the job. They are executed first at the beginning of the job